# Remote Desktop is not geting through Wi-Fi

Tags: network-core

I had a network which is accessible through LAN and Wi-Fi but the problem is while using Wi-Fi we can't ping to any PC, and that's why we can't remotely connect to any PC.

As Wi-Fi and LAN are on the same network it should ping and remotely connect, but it doesn't work. So please tell me why this is happening, and how we can resolve the problem.

Comment: this question is more related to supper user group , any way it most probably  due to security issue

Comment: Maybe there is a VLAN specific for your Wifi which is not the same for you LAN.

Comment: You don't provide enough information. A diagram with some details would help.

Answer (score 2):

You must do a review of your wifi conf, cause, sometimes, it has enable a configuration that does user isolation, with the finally of a security measure to isolate users. On this cases, is thinking that you gonna put your wifi network in other network, dedicated for that.

Comment: I second this, check for client isolation settings in your equipment.